# backend list: sort and filter by field in HasMany relation

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

### backend list: sort and filter by field in HasMany relation

I have a two related Models with theatre productions and their performances:

```
class Play extends Model
{
 ...
public $table = 'johar_theater_plays';
public $hasMany = ['playtimes' => 'johar\Theater\Models\PlayTime'];
}

class PlayTime extends Model
{
...
public $table = 'johar_theater_plays_times';
public $belongsTo = ['play' =>  ['johar\Theater\Models\Play']];
}
```

I will manage playtimes via Relation Manager in the `play` form.

To show the `playtimes` in the `play`-list there are two possibilities I found:

```
playtimes:
    relation: playtimes
    select: time
    type: myRenderFunction

playtimes:        
    type: myRenderFunction
    sortable: true
```

The first type calls my function with a collection in `$value`, the second one with a JSON string.

In the second type, I can sort by playtimes - it probably just sorts the JSON string, but that would be OK.

**But I found no way to create a filter scope to filter out all plays that have no performance after today.** 
I tried

```
scope:
  condition: playtimes.time > now()
```

and imho all possible variations of it. As well as creating a scope-function where I tinkered with different where clauses.
The problem is always that the SQL puts the JOIN into a group_concat:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'time' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select `johar_theater_plays`.*, 
    (select group_concat(time separator ', ') 
    from `johar_theater_plays_times` 
    where `johar_theater_plays_times`.`play_id` = `johar_theater_plays`.`id`)
    as `playtimes` 
from `johar_theater_plays` 
where `time` &gt; 2016-12-12 00:00:00 
order by `playtimes` desc)" on line 662 of E:\..\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
```

**So the short question is:**
How can I filter and Sort by playtimes.time (or FIRST(playtimes.time)) in the List of Plays, when a `Play` HasMany `Playtimes`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I would be glad if someone has one thats more beautiful, but for now I will work with this scope Function:

```
public function scopeFutureonly($query)
{
    $table = 'johar_theater_plays_times';
    if(!$this->is_scoped) {
        $query->join($table, 'johar_theater_plays.id', '=', $table . '.play_id');
        $query->groupBy($table . '.play_id');
        $query->where($table . '.time', '>', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    }
    $this->is_scoped = true;
}
```

`isScoped` is a protected variable in the Model to prevent adding the query multiple times when the scope is called more than once. (Thanks to [planetadeleste here](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/problem-with-scope-filter-in-listcontroller)).

The only Problem is, I get two JOINS in the SQL: one in the concat and one regular. I think this can only be circumvented by creating the SQL fully by hand, which would defeat the purpose of october here....